# SQL - Calculate 30 days ago and delete

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to clear a MySQL database of entries in a table that are older than 30 days.

I think I am correct by doing it like this...

```
DELETE from wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE date_created < '11/05/18'
```

But is there a way I can get the SQL statement to calculate 30 days ago automatically?  That way I could set a cronjob up and have it run everyday without me having to manually enter the date.

Comment: 11/05/18 is not a valid date in our universe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`curdate()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) to get the current date and [`date_add()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to subtract 30 days from it.

```
date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL -30 DAY);
```

Comment: Nice! That will save me having to do things manually. Can I just add this in place of the defined date? DELETE from wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE date_created < date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL -30 DAY);

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks for the pointers.  Reading up on curdate to make sure I fully understand it

Answer (score 1):

Use date_add and sysdate functions to calculate date dynamically.

```
 Date_add(sysdate(), interval -30 days)
```